# Call a web api from another web api

Tags: architecture, restful-architecture, software-design

I have a Windows Service with a Web API interface. I use this service to upload data from one system to another.

My problem is that the other system, the one where I have to upload the data, is a Web API service and I'm not sure if it is a good idea make a web api call to make another web api call inside. Maybe I can upload the data directly to that Web API system without using the Windows Service.

This Windows Service exists because the program with the data to upload doesn't need to know where I will upload the data. On the Windows Service I can change the web api to a stored procedure to upload the data by configuration. I'm trying to create a decouple system. Note: the stored procedure will upload the data to a different database that the database used in the Web API system.

But I can create a decouple system if Windows Service has the same API interface that the other system with the API interface. And on my program to upload I change the url from Windows Service to the Web API system.

What do you think about this design? Is it a good idea call a web api from a web api when I can call it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do you think about this design? Is it a good idea call a web api from a web api when I can call it directly?

It's called service proxy, or gateway, or facade. Not sure what was the original name and who claimed it, but there's nothing wrong in using it. In fact, it's very common to hide the target service behind the proxy. Additional functionality can be added later if needed. For example, you could introduce a retry logic, caching, load balancing, new service calls, custom error handling, or even new technology without impacting existing consumers. Basically, this is the proper way to maintain versioning of your services. If you exposed `/api/v1/upload` and decided to introduce `/api/v2/upload` with additional fields A-Z, you could hide `v1` behind `v2` and send default values instead of A-Z. I'm not saying it's good design, but I'm sure you've seen it. Hiding async API behind sync API is another example, not really good though.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on your purpose, call a wep api from a web api is usually used when:
- You need to avoid cross-domain
- You need to adaptive some interface but do not want to change the original one
- You would like to make some more action before doing the original API

In your case, it is ok to do it.